# PIG cannot understand hbase table data

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, hbasestorage

I'm running hbase(0.94.13) on a single node for my academic project. After loading data into hbase tables, I'm trying to run pig(0.11.1) scripts on the data using HBaseStorage. However this throws an error saying

> IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair: �\00\00\00

here is the load command I'm using in Pig

> books = LOAD 'hbase://booksdb' USING
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('details:title','-loadKey
>   true') AS     (ID:chararray,title:chararray);

I thought this might be a problem of hbase being a different version in pig than what my machine has. But can't seem to make it work without downgrading my hbase. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to submit a pig job remotely
if so you'd need to add a few settings in the pig.properties file (or set setting_name='values' in your script)

```
hbase.zookeeper.quorum=<node>
hadoop.job.ugi=username,groupname
fs.default.name=hdfs://<node>:port
mapred.job.tracker=hdfs://<node>:port
```